# How to unit test event subscription

Tags: unit-testing, events, c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

I want to be able to unit test a custom collection that I'm writing, which needs to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the objects that are added to the collection.  And then unsubscribe from the events when they are removed.

This is not a big deal when the items added to the collection are an interface, I can mock that (using Rhino Mocks) and `Expect` the subscriptions.  But in one instance, the items being added are actual classes and I can't mock the events because they are not virtual.

Is there another way I can test that these classes have their `PropertyChanged` event properly subscribed and unsubscribed?

Answer (score 3):

In lieu of using a mock can you simply add a property to the concrete type that will tell you if the event has a subscription or not?  Just a suggestion.  This may not jive with the overall design and/or rest of your unit tests using a mocked interface.

```
class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public bool PropertyChangedSubscribed
   {
      get { return PropertyChanged != null; }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

// unit test code
var someClass = new SomeClass();
Assert.IsFalse(otherClass.PropertyChangedSubscribed);
someClass.PropertyChanged += SubscribedMethod;
Assert.IsTrue(otherClass.PropertyChangedSubscribed);
```

Comment: I considered this approach, my problem is that some of these classes are generated with T4 templates based on "model" classes (the classes I'm testing are part of the view model).  So I'd have to modify my T4 templates which would add this extra bit of code to all 140+ model classes.  I hate to do something like that just to facilitate a unit test.

Comment: Ouch!  Yeah, I figured there may be some deeper issue here; and I fully agree to the point about not adding code simply to facilitate a unit test.  I probably wouldn't do this either.  It's just a way I could think of to do it.